# Need an SQL query that will left join with another table, which will in turn return the latest values based on time, grouped into a single row

Tags: sql, inner-join, greatest-n-per-group, presto, amazon-athena

I need help with a SELECT SQL query that will left join with another table on id column, which will in turn return the latest values based on time, grouped into a single row?

Basically, join the two tables in such a way that for each record in users table that exists in time_series table, return the latest values based on time grouped into a single row.

users table:

```
id  |  name
----+--------
 1  | "Joe" 
 2  | "Ron"
```

time_series table:

```
time| id  |  a  |  b  | c  | d
----+-----+-----+-----+----+----
 1  |  1  |  a1 |     |    |
 2  |  1  |     |  b1 |    |
 3  |  1  |     |     | c0 |
 4  |  1  |  a3 |     | c3 |
 5  |  1  |  a0 |     |    |
 6  |  2  |  a3 |     | c3 | d1
 7  |  2  |  a2 |     |    | d3
```

The result should look like this:

```
id  |  a  |  b  | c  | d  | name
----+-----+-----+----+----+------
 1  |  a0 |  b1 | c3 |    | "Joe"
 2  |  a2 |     |    | d3 | "Ron"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses a couple of subqueries:

```
select u.*,
    (select ts.a from time_series ts where ts.id = u.id and ts.a is not null order by ts.time desc limit 1) a,
    (select ts.b from time_series ts where ts.id = u.id and ts.b is not null order by ts.time desc limit 1) b,
    (select ts.c from time_series ts where ts.id = u.id and ts.c is not null order by ts.time desc limit 1) c,
    (select ts.d from time_series ts where ts.id = u.id and ts.d is not null order by ts.time desc limit 1) d
from users u
```

Another solution is to rank rows with `row_number()` for each column, giving priority to non-`null` values, and thenconditional aggregation:

```
select u.id,
    max(case when ts.rn_a = 1 then ts.a end) a,
    max(case when ts.rn_b = 1 then ts.b end) a,
    max(case when ts.rn_c = 1 then ts.c end) a,
    max(case when ts.rn_d = 1 then ts.d end) d
from users u
inner join (
    select ts.*,
        row_number() over(order by (case when a is null then 1 else 0 end), time desc) rn_a,
        row_number() over(order by (case when b is null then 1 else 0 end), time desc) rn_b,
        row_number() over(order by (case when c is null then 1 else 0 end), time desc) rn_c,
        row_number() over(order by (case when d is null then 1 else 0 end), time desc) rn_d
    from time_series ts
) ts on ts.id = u.id
group by u.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the function you're looking for is `coalesce`.

```
SELECT u.id
    , coalesce(a)
    , coalesce(b)
    , coalesce(c)
    , coalesce(d)
    , name
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN time_series ts
    ON u.id = ts.id
GROUP BY 1, 6
ORDER BY ts.time DESC;
```